# Input string with space in SAS

Tags: regex, sas

I am inputting strings into a data set in SAS. Here is my code.

```
data match;
input string1 $1-6
      string2 $10-15
      string3 $18-21;
position1=prxmatch('/^a/', string1);
position2=prxmatch('/a$/', string2);
position3=prxmatch('/^a.a$/', string3);
datalines;
abc      aba     aa
abcde    abcba   abba
 abcde   aaaaa   a.a
                 a$a
;
run;
```

As you may notice, the last row of first column `abcde` starts with a space. Besides, the last string of second column `aaaaa` ends with a space, too. Except for these two, other strings are just who they are.

I am using `prxmatch` for regular expression matching. So `prxmatch('/^a/', ' abcde')` should return me 0, and `prxmatch('/a$/', 'aaaaa ')` should return me 0 too.

However, the result looks like this:

[image: System Results]

So, what should I do to input these strings correctly and get the right regular expression matching result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$CHARw.` informat to read in initial spaces. I prefer `@pos` to read in that way:

```
data match;
input @1 string1 $char6.
      @10 string2  $char6.
      @18 string3  $char4.;
  position1=prxmatch('/^a/', string1);
  position2=prxmatch('/a$/', string2);
  position3=prxmatch('/^a.a$/', string3);
datalines;
abc      aba     aa
abcde    abcba   abba
 abcde   aaaaa   a.a
                 a$a
;
run;
```

I think that now returns what you expect.  (You may intend STRING3 to have only 3 wide? )

Comment: String3 has 4 wide, from 18 to 21. The `position` works well, however, `position2` and `position3` doesn't work as I need. They all return 0.

Comment: I add a `trim()` but the last one in second column still doesn't work well.

Comment: What do you mean by the last one in the second column?   You mean the " aaaaa"?

Comment: Adding trim matches the "aaaaa" perfectly for me.

Comment: No, it's not 'aaaaa', it's 'aaaaa  ', with a space in the end... It would be cut in trim.

Comment: Right.  And it is trimmed to "aaaaa" and works perfectly for me.

Comment: SAS returns 5, when `prxmatch('/a$/', trim('aaaaa    ')`, which should be 0, because a space is not a match for a. That's not I want originally. But without `trim()`, `aba` won't match, which should be a match. I'm so struggling right now.

Comment: You have to pick one - either trim or don't.  You can't have it both ways.  What's the difference between the two?  Why should `"aba   "` match and not `"aaaaa "`?

Comment: The second column would be `'aba'`, `'abcba'` and `'aaaaa  '`. So `'aba'` and `'abcba'` would be a match, and `'aaaaa  '` would not. That's the situation of `a$` I would to show.

Comment: You can't have that.  The second column is "aba   ", "abcba ", and "aaaaa ".  SAS doesn't have varchar concept - all character fields are padded by spaces.  Unless you have a non-breaking space in the "aaaaa " which you can then differentiate from a regular space, you're stuck.

Comment: Thank you. I get it, I will try another way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow for whitespace at the beginning or end of each column, use `\s*`:

```
position1=prxmatch('/^\s*a/', string1);
position2=prxmatch('/a\s*$/', string2);
position3=prxmatch('/^a.a$/', string3);
```